# Wordpress menu saving issue

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a [website](http://www.competitionmantra.com) developed in wordpress. The problem is that when I add menu items in menu and click on save, it won't save the menu and menu-items order changed automatically. Is there any solution?

Comment: how many menu items there??

Comment: it has a big amount of menu-items almost 400 and i already written max_input_vars = 20000.

Comment: okay did you check this,https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134#comment:61

Comment: which version do you have??

Comment: yes i did but that is also a problem question.

Comment: i have latest version of wordpress and 5.4 of php

Comment: you mean 4.7 version\

Comment: no it is version 4.6.1

Comment: ok please check error log in cpanel is there any update??

Comment: no there is no error regarding this in error log. last log message is of 11:17 today then not any log message.

Comment: This user should really stop spamming stupid questions!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a simple solution to this problem from the WordPress forum.
Simply add the following:

```
php_value max_input_vars 5000
```

into your .htaccess file.After being stuck with limit of 89 menu items for over a year, I now have 95 and increasing. I have no idea what, if any, is the new upper limit.If still have issue then contact your host provider to extend limit for this.

Comment: where in .htaccess file ?

Comment: root folder there is htaccess.its hidden so you have to first make it visible

Comment: i added this before closing IfModule, is this ok ?

Comment: No you just have to add

Comment: i added ths in .htaccess but can't solve a problem. would you like to see my error log ?